# std::getline(std::cin, custom_class); type mismatch

Tags: c++, oop, templates, cin

This is my custom string class (xstring.hpp):

```
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

namespace
{
    using std::vector;
    using std::istringstream;

    template <class strT>
    class xstring_base
    {
        private:
            strT str;

        public:
            operator strT&() {return str;}
            vector<strT>* tokenize();

            // constructors
            xstring_base<strT>(strT);
    };
}
#include "xstring.cpp"

#include <string>
typedef xstring_base<std::string> xstring;
```

I've put the `operator strT&()` to mimic the Standard Library's string behavior wherever needed, and this class works absolutely fine when I initialize it with a C-style string, even containing non-ASCII code, for example arabic, but `std::getline` complains that xstring is not supported.

How can I use `getline` to input from `cin` to this custom string class of mine?

(I use g++ on Kubuntu 11.10. Gives tens of lines of complain about template mixture mismatches...)

Thanks so much!

Comment: I honestly can't tell why you'd want to do this. Why make yet another string lookalike?

Comment: Because I need some custom functionality such as tokenizing, some custom kinds of conversions and manipulation, ... and also I need it to work for ALL languages, that's why I used template. :-)

Comment: @BillyONeal: It's not another string lookalike; it's a wrapper to add functions to an existing string class. Although I can't tell why you'd want that rather than non-member functions.

Comment: @ai64: Templates don't work in "ALL languages". I don't see why you can't implement anything you want as a set of functions. In C++, one should prefer nonmember functions to member functions wherever possible.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: The `operator str&` effectively makes it a string lookalike.

Comment: Well, both of you guys ought to be right, and also please take a look at my reputation! TOTAL NEWBIE :-D. However I think its worth knowing, perhaps to anyone, how to cope with such a case. I'd be glad to know of your solutions to this getline challenge I'm facing :-) Thank you!

Comment: @ai64 Very bad idea. Write some free functions, they are [better than member functions](http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184401197). Or better yet, use [Boost.StringAlgorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/string_algo.html).

Comment: @PaulManta Boost programmers have definitely done such things when they were newbie too, right? The more we rely on libraries without knowing of their inner workings, the more we're adding to our ignorance rather than knowledge. Please! There ought to be some way to do what I wanna do, am I wrong?

Comment: @ai64 I read your second last comment after I posted mine. Nothing wrong with being a novice, and yes, you probably shouldn't bother with Boost if you are one, but keep it in mind. But you should take note about member functions v. free functions.

Comment: @PaulManta You're right, I've also read in books that THAT is the right thing to do, but shouldn't we ever try such so called "silly" things? I think we'll definitely need to deepen our knowledge trough such talks. That's what we come here to do, right? Challenging each other's depth of knowledge to give each other motivation to go learn  more. So, I'm not insisting that what I'm doing is right, but I wanna say that this is also a possible action, so if we wanna become better programmers we must know these TOO BESIDES typical recipes. And thank you for challenging me! :-)

Comment: @ai64 No problem! :P You're right.

Comment: @ai64: I actually must disagree. The fact that you are NOVICE means that you better use *well-designed* libraries before trying to reinvent the square-wheel. Some very smart people with a good amount of experience have thought the problem over and decided to use a particular API. Get familiar with it, try to think *why* that is *better* than other options, and if in doubt ask. Trying to write your own might lead you to *design* issues that seem to work and that you will learn as the *right* thing to do. For example, you should avoid implicit conversions, that seem to be required in your design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::getline` is a function template that looks like this:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator >
std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& getline( std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& input,
                                           std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>& str );
```

When you call `std::getline(std::cin, x)`, you don't provide template arguments. This means that the types will have to be deduced from the arguments.

However, the type deduction algorithm does not take user-defined conversions into account. So your conversion operator is not used. If you wrote `std::getline<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>(std::cin, x)`, no type deduction is needed, so the conversion operator would be considered.

Comment: It *does* take implicit conversions into account, just no user-defined conversions.

Comment: @Xeo: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: `template <typename T> struct X {}; template <typename T> f(X<T> const volatile*); X x; f(&x);` has a builtin implicit conversion from `X<T>*` to `X<T> const volatile*`.

Comment: @Xeo: no. The type deduction algorithm can only find perfect matches, with no conversions. For a simple test, try `std::min( 1, (short)2 )` and see the error message.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas See the example in my comment. It's not a perfect match, and it works. The problem in yours that `T` is deduced to be two different things.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Uhm... you forced me to go back to the standard... You are right in that *some* conversions are allowed, but not all *implicit conversions* are allowed either. If the type of the argument in the function being deduced is a *reference* then the deduced type can be a perfect match or a more cv-qualified type (14.8.2.1) but nothing else, which is one of the only three exceptions to the *perfect match* rule (the others referring to pointer/pointer to member and class types)

Comment: @David: I elaborated on that in the Lounge starting [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2842120#2842120).

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this fails is rather arcane - basically, `std::getline` is a template, and the template arguments can only be deduced when the argument is a specialisation of `std::basic_string` (such as `std::string`) - type conversions aren't be considered in this case.

The best solution is not to try to wrap existing string types, but rather to write non-member functions to add the functionality you need:

```
template <typename String>
std::vector<String> tokenise(String const &);
```

If you really want a wrapper type for some reason, then you would have to either explicitly convert to the string type, or provide the template arguments:

```
std::getline(std::cin, static_cast<std::string&>(xs));
std::getline<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::cin, xs);
```

Comment: I really appreciate that, thank you! However I'll still curiously look for an answer to MEMBER functions solution too. But thanks anyway ;-)

Comment: And thank you so much Mike. That's what I was after. Thank you. :-)